# MVC approach in Node.js

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller

Currently I am working on `Node.js` using the `MVC` type of model, as it is easier to segregate the code into modules.

What I am looking for is a better approach apart from `MVC`, so that the code can be easily debugged and understandable.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used quite a few different frameworks but I've always found Sails.js to be the best MVC Framework for Node, easy to learn and offers a lot, its basically express with a lot of middleware but they make creating Controllers, Models and what not very easy with their CLI, you can check our more here:

http://sailsjs.org/